# Content query webpart display url

Tags: content-query-web-part

I AM Creating one list with url and description . i want display items using content query webpart . i am selecting title and description in style , given the column names . but it display url like httpsgoogle ,goolge but i need to display google only not complete url path .

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@Title,',')"/>
```

OR if value is stored in variable then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($YourVariable,',')"/>
```